# is implementing ASIFT in php possible?

Tags: java, php, image

we are going to make an online classified ad for our thesis and we are going to implement some image comparison to filter out images that are inappropriate. http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/my-asift/ 
based on this demo, ASIFT can match more keypoints than SIFT. how do u suppose we should implement this? should we use java? or can we just stick to php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php is slow, its not a compiled language like Java or C++ (the source the website you quoted used) PHP is written in C though so the function could be compiled in without too much difficultly.

I would suggest a better solution would be putting the images in a folder and then processing with C++ or C directly and moving them to a "safe" folder which PHP reads from and displays.

http://dannagle.com/2011/09/benchmarking-c-versus-java-versus-php-programming-languages/
not a "full" test but as an example of the speed difference.

It is entirtely possible though to implement it in PHP, Speed would be a huge issue though